# Receber informações compartilhadas pelo Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Tenho uma aplicação onde é possível compartilhar links! 
Faço isso pegando as informações do `meta` `og` com o Jsoup:

```
  final Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            final Elements itens = doc.select("meta[property^=og:]");

            if (itens.size() <= 0) {
                return null;
            }

            final ObjectPreview objectPreview = new ObjectPreview();
            objectPreview.url = url;

            for (int i = 0; i < itens.size(); i++) {
                Element tag = itens.get(i);

                String text = tag.attr("property");
                if ("og:image".equals(text)) {
                    objectPreview.image = tag.attr("content");
                } else if ("og:description".equals(text)) {
                    objectPreview.description = tag.attr("content");
                } else if ("og:title".equals(text)) {
                    objectPreview.title = tag.attr("content");
                }
            }
```

Gostaria de pegar estas informações através do App do Google Maps:

1. Quando é compartilhado com o Maps além da url, vem o nome do Local.

Ex.: `Restaurante Come come \n https://url/mapa/c0009080`

Até aí tudo bem!

(Fiz uma bela gambiarra: `split` no `http` e boa!)

2. Quando tento pegar os elementos (código acima) não consigo acessar estas informações!

Como consigo pegar estas informações (assim como o WhatsApp faz) de um link vindo do Google Maps?